# How to send multiple Identifier in Tabledit jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabledit

I am using Tabledit-jquery to edit table.Firstly i have set one identifier and multiple editable columns which totally works fine by following.

https://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/live-table-data-edit-delete-using-tabledit-plugin-in-php.html

Now i want to set two identifier which does not working.
How can i set multiple identifer with tabledit?

I tried to create a 2-D array  for identifier as used for editable.

```
   identifier:[[1, "id"], [2, "id2"]],
   editable:[[3, 'Session'], [4, 'Grade']],


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#editable_table').Tabledit({
      url:'action3.php',
      columns:{
       identifier:[[1, "id"], [2, "id2"]],
       editable:[[3, 'Session'], [4, 'Grade']],
      },
      restoreButton:false,
      deleteButton: false,
         });

});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

just tried the code from your source at webslessons, it worked at the first try. (Honestly, second try, I only had to add the file jquery.tabledit.min.js into the directory.)

Now regarding your question. Tabledit does not work with two identifiers per se. What you can do is to dump the two identifiers into one column. I changed the code from webslessons to this end. Therefore I used a kind of handmade serialization of the two identifiers by just putting them after each other separated by a semicolon.

```
$id_ser = $row[0].";".$row[1];
```

And I use this "serialized" id as values for the first column of the displayed table. (Serialization by the php function serialize() did not work, as there are quotations marks generated by the function, which are not transportet well by the INPUT_POST of tabledit.) Within the file "action.php" one has to "unserialize" the $id_ser back. This is achieved using a regular expression:

```
$id_array = preg_split("/;/",$id_ser);
```

I will add the changed code here. Be sure also to adopt the code for actions "edit" and "delete" within the file "action.php". Hope it is useful.

index.php:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_2_ids";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
<html>
 <head>
          <title>Live Table Data Edit Delete using Tabledit Plugin in PHP</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.tabledit.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
            <div class="table-responsive">
    <h3 align="center">Live Table Data Edit Delete using Tabledit Plugin in PHP</h3><br />
    <table id="editable_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>ID1;ID2</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $id_ser = $row[0].";".$row[1];  # extract first and second entry of the row.
      echo '
      <tr>
       <td>'.$id_ser.'</td>
       <td>'.$row["last_name"].'</td>
      </tr>
      ';
     }
     ?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

action.php:

```
<?php
//action.php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testing');

$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

$id_ser = $input["id_ser"];
$id_array = preg_split("/;/",$id_ser);

if($input["action"] === 'edit')
{
 $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["last_name"]);
 $query = "
 UPDATE tbl_2_ids
 SET last_name = '".$last_name."'
 WHERE id0 = '".$id_array[0]."'
 AND id1 = '".$id_array[1]."'
 ";
 mysqli_query($connect, $query);

}
if($input["action"] === 'delete')
{
 $query = "
 DELETE FROM tbl_2_ids
 WHERE id0 = '".$id_array[0]."'
 AND id1 = '".$id_array[1]."'
 ";
 mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}

echo json_encode($input);

?>
```

In order to create the database "testing" with the tabel "tbl_2_ids" you can use the following batch file "database_mysql.batch".
For mysql perform the batch file by the command:

```
mysql -u root -p < database_mysql.batch
```

database_mysql.batch:

```
--
-- Database: `testing`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testing;
USE testing;

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_2ids`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_2_ids` (
  `id0` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
DELETE FROM tbl_2_ids;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_user`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_2_ids` (`id0`, `id1`, `last_name`) VALUES
(2, 20, 'Smith'),
(3, 21, 'Ferrari'),
(4, 22, 'Mitten'),
(5, 23, 'Noyes'),
(6, 24, 'William'),
(7, 25, 'Hise'),
(8, 26, 'Aguinaldo'),
(9, 27, 'Goad'),
(10, 28, 'Simons'),
(11, 29, 'Huber'),
(12, 30, 'Soliz'),
(13, 31, 'Dismuke'),
(14, 32, 'Thomas');
```

If there is a password, you will have to give it on the command line. Also within the files "index.php" and "action.php" you will have to give the authentification for root instead of "" in the file, if you have configured a root password.

Answer (score 0):

feli_x thanks for your suggestions and efforts. I have just resolve my issue by modifying tableedit plugin. Now i can add multiple identifier.

```
columns: {
                identifier: function() {
                    // Hide identifier column.
                    if (settings.hideIdentifier) {
                        $table.find('th:nth-child(' + parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[0]) + 1 + '), tbody td:nth-child(' + parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[0]) + 1 + ')').hide();
                    }
                  for (var i = 0; i < settings.columns.identifier.length; i++) {
                    var $td = $table.find('tbody td:nth-child(' + (parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[i][0]) + 1) + ')');

                    $td.each(function() {
                        // Create hidden input with row identifier.
                        var span = '<span class="tabledit-span tabledit-identifier">' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
                        var input = '<input class="tabledit-input tabledit-identifier" type="hidden" name="' + settings.columns.identifier[i][1] + '" value="' + $(this).text() + '" disabled>';

                        // Add elements to table cell.
                        $(this).html(span + input);

                        // Add attribute "id" to table row.
                        $(this).parent('tr').attr(settings.rowIdentifier, $(this).text());
                    });
                  }
                },
```

Comment: I see you added the for-loop `for (var i = 0; i < settings.columns.identifier.length; i++) { ...`
inside the jquery.tabledit.js library. Fine that this works for you. For curiosity, why do you want to use multiple identifiers, isn't one enough? Normally it should suffice to have a unique marker for one row.